# Office 365 Management Activity API returning Internal Server Errors

Tags: office365, office365api

We use the Office 365 Management Activity API for our SIEM tool to pull in O365 and Azure AD logs for monitoring. The scripts that we have had running for awhile now have just started failing today (or so we noticed) with this error:

[body] => {"error":{"code":"AF50005","message":"An internal error occurred.  Retry the request."}}

I'm not seeing any errors on the status pages or any known issue posts, wondering if anyone else is seeing these.

We started seeing these failures in our logging around 02/11/2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an ongoing intermittent issue in the Management Activity API during the past week. The engineering team is deploying a fix across regions. The deployment is done in the NA region with EMEA and APAC to follow. The ETA for the worldwide deployment of this fix is close of business today, Feb. 14th.

Comment: Confirmed it's working for us, sorry for the slow reply here. We ended up having to remove our own publisher ID from the end of the API call as well but things look better. Thanks for the follow up here and my apologies for the slow response back.

Answer (score 1):

The latency issues have been resolved. Please check again and confirm